# can I use Zend_Service_LiveDocx to READ .doc and .docx content and convert it into text...?

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-format, zend-controller

I want to READ ( not write into) .doc and .docx files and need to extract text out of them..

I tried many methods but some works good only for .docx and not for .doc

I got to know that Zend_Service_LiveDocx can do this but not sure how to do it...

Please let me know details regrading this and if there are any more method just to READ contents from .docx and .doc files...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

All classes in Zend_Service are tied to an online service (Ebay,Flickr,Twitter etc). LiveDocx is also an online service and requires a user account ([Registration](https://www.livedocx.com/user/account_registration.aspx)).

If you use their service you should be able to read documents but only when hosted with them and not locale on your server which I guess is what you are looking for. The [Zend LiveDocx guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.service.livedocx.html) has more info.